# IndexError in scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-regression

I am attempting to use the curve_fit function in scipy to model some data. I have 5 sets of data that will be added together with different weightings to fit the observed data y.

```
def model(kidx, c10,c20,c40,c80,c160):
    mod = (c10*data['10'][kidx] + 
           c20*data['20'][kidx] + 
           c40*data['40'][kidx] + 
           c80*data['80'][kidx] + 
           c160*data['160'][kidx])
    return mod

curve_fit(model, k, y)
```

data is a dictionary containing numpy arrays, k is a list of indices, and y is the target data. When I run this code, it returns an IndexError:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-51aba3bc37c2> in <module>
----> 1 curve_fit(model, k, y)

~/.conda/envs/heinrich/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, **kwargs)
    750         # Remove full_output from kwargs, otherwise we're passing it in twice.
    751         return_full = kwargs.pop('full_output', False)
--> 752         res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
    753         popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier = res
    754         cost = np.sum(infodict['fvec'] ** 2)

~/.conda/envs/heinrich/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    381     if not isinstance(args, tuple):
    382         args = (args,)
--> 383     shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
    384     m = shape[0]
    385 

~/.conda/envs/heinrich/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs, output_shape)
     24 def _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs,
     25                 output_shape=None):
---> 26     res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
     27     if (output_shape is not None) and (shape(res) != output_shape):
     28         if (output_shape[0] != 1):

~/.conda/envs/heinrich/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in func_wrapped(params)
    456     if transform is None:
    457         def func_wrapped(params):
--> 458             return func(xdata, *params) - ydata
    459     elif transform.ndim == 1:
    460         def func_wrapped(params):

<ipython-input-17-8bc44c07046b> in model(kidx, c10, c20, c40, c80, c160)
      1 def model(kidx, c10,c20,c40,c80,c160):
----> 2     mod = c10*data['10'][kidx] + c20*data['20'][kidx] + c40*data['40'][kidx] + c80*data['80'][kidx] + c160*data['160'][kidx]
      3     return mod

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

What is going on here? k is an array of integers, and it is the only one that could be used as an index. none of these variables are previously used in the notebook.

Comment: Add a `print(kidx)` line to your `model` function, so you have clear idea of what value `fit` is passing to this function.  When using `scipy` functions like this pay close attention to what the docs say about your function, and what arguments it's supposed to accept.  Don't guess.  test.

Answer (score 0):

You might be *calling* `curve_fit` with `k` as an array of integers, but the method converts it to a floating-point type [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/adc4f4f7bab120ccfab9383aba272954a0a12fb0/scipy/optimize/minpack.py#L720).

This makes sense, when you think about it. The `curve_fit` method is generally used to predict `y` data from a variable (predictor) assumed to be continuous. This is generally how the optimizer makes progress, by assuming that it can make small adjustments to the input `x` array and determine what directions will improve the fit. This doesn't make sense if the input data is an indexing array, rather than an actual position in the search space.

You should rewrite your `model` function to accept the predictors as an array of floats. There's really no other way around this, short of writing a custom optimizer that knows how to "search" through the indices. That's a lot of work, and probably not what you want anyway. So the former approach should be preferred.

#### Edit:

Actually, it looks like `kidx` might be constant throughout the process of optimization. That is, you're always selecting the same elements of `data` to make your prediction. If that's the case, just index it once at the beginning and pass that to the model function, but *not* as an argument to the `curve_fit` routine.

Comment: The problem we are working to solve involves comparing the observed y, which is a 1D array, to the simulated data, which is a dictionary of 1D arrays. There is no function that models the observed data, so I do not see how the model function could be rewritten to accept floats. Is there another module that might make more sense to use in this situation?

Comment: Of course there's a function that models the observed data. You're using it: a weighted sum of the arrays in `data`. What I meant by my edit is, ask yourself if `kidx` changes during the optimization. If the answer is "no", then you don't need to pass it to `model`, and then you can avoid this problem entirely. If the answer is "yes", then you'll need to look into another type of optimization procedure besides `curve_fit`. Dynamic programming might be a fit, but it really depends on the details of your problem.